# Input width with type submit less than input with type text

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why input width with type submit less than input with type text. Could you help me with it?

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test" />
</div>
<div class="test">
    <input type="text" placeholder="test" />
</div>
<div class="test">
    <input type="submit" value="test" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dve2h1dt/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two `input` types have their own default styling (margin, padding etc). In order to include these in the width calculation to normalize the set width, use `box-sizing:border-box;`

Change your CSS to:

```
input {
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[**More on `box-sizing` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

> The box-sizing CSS property is used to alter the default CSS box model
>   used to calculate widths and heights of elements.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/dve2h1dt/3/)**

The box model being used is different for both the inputs, you can make the box models the same by specifying them `box-sizing`

css

```
input {
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```